# In Corda, when should a `FungibleAsset` subclass `OnLedgerAsset`?

Tags: corda

In Corda, assets that can be split and merged should be represented using the `FungibleAsset` interface.

The `finance` package defines a further `OnLedgerAsset` class that seems to provide similar functionality for issuing, splitting, merging and exits fungible assets.

If I'm defining my own fungible asset, should I subclass the `OnLedgerAsset` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FungibleAsset` is defined in Corda Core, and is used by the node's vault to split and merge fungible assets. All fungible assets should implement it.

`OnLedgerAsset` is defined in the `finance` package. It is used to ensure that all the fungible assets defined in the `finance` package have additional common methods for issuance, splitting, merging and exiting. The `finance` package remains unstable (see https://docs.corda.net/corda-api.html#corda-incubating-modules), and its API is likely to change extensively in the future to meet the requirements of real businesses.

I'd therefore recommend that you do not implement `OnLedgerAsset` for now. Much of the functionality provided by `OnLedgerAsset` will likely be moved into the node's vault in the future.

Comment: This would mean if I'm creating my own Fungible asset, I've to write my own issuance, splitting, merging and exiting methods or flows.

Comment: Yes, for now. This behaviour will hopefully be built into the node's vault/Corda Core in the future.

Comment: It leads to writing your own algorithm for coin or state selection problem when considering which state to spend or transfer.  is there any other way around or some inbuilt function to use? Cash uses generateSpend in OnLedgerAsset for coin selection. couldn't find what Commodity contract uses...